# How do you get the bad key brand sword?

Tags: terraria-mobile

So my cousin has this sword called a bad key brand sword and I want to know how to get it. Is there a crafting recipe? Do I find it in chests? Is it a rare drop?

Comment: He says it's a very good sword and is very powerful.

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing I have been able to find is the [Keybrand](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Keybrand) weapon. [image: The Keybrand!]

The [Gamepedia](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Terraria_Wiki) lists the weapon as a 0.33% drop from the following enemies:

- [Blue Armored Bones](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Blue_Armored_Bones)
- [Hell Armored Bones](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hell_Armored_Bones)
- [Rusty Armored Bones](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Rusty_Armored_Bones)

These enemies appear in the [Dungeon](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dungeon), after defeating [Plantera](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Plantera) on [Hard Mode](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hardmode).

#### Keybrand Stats

- **Damage:** 70
- **Knock-back:** 6.5
- **Attack Speed:** 19 (very fast)
- **Critical Chance:** 4%
- **Rarity:** Yellow
- **Sell Value:** 2G 76S